# How to execute a project from a GitHub repository designed for Windows on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, github, raspberry-pi

I've discovered a GitHub repository project that functions on Windows, but I'm interested in adapting it to work on Raspberry Pi OS (I'm using a Raspberry Pi 5).

Here is the link of the repository : https://github.com/maddinkunze/handcode.git

There is a description provided in the repository which is regarding installation on other platforms,

"If you wish to build this for other platforms, you have to include the svg2gcode binary for your platform in the src/lib/svg2gcode subdirectory and change the os.system(...) call in converttogcode(...) within src/convert.py to point to your platform-specific binary."

I've installed svg2gcode, but I'm unsure how to proceed with balance steps, and I've been unable to locate the convert.py file.

Comment: `svg2gcode` vs `svg2code`. You miiight have a typo there

Comment: Thank you for bringing it to my attention; it has been corrected.

Comment: ***DO NOT*** post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)